# How do I enforce common slope in geom_smooth()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set, something similar to `tb` as generated below:

```
x = seq(0, 10, by=.4)
y1 = x + rnorm(x)
y2 = .25 + 1.25*x + rnorm(x)
tb = bind_rows(tibble(x=x, y=y1, z=F), tibble(x=x, y=y2, z=T))
```

Note that `z` is an indicator variable. I have calculated linear regression in R:

```
summary(lm(y ~ x + z, data=tb))
```

resulting in

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + z, data = tb)
Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.84417 -0.79490 -0.02323  0.64194  2.37092 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.5971     0.2951  -2.024   0.0485 *  
x             1.1068     0.0450  24.597  < 2e-16 ***
zTRUE         1.6958     0.2700   6.281 8.62e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9735 on 49 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9293,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9265 
F-statistic: 322.2 on 2 and 49 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now I'd like to plot the data and the regression lines. However, `geom_smooth()` treats two subsets, with the different indicator value, as completely independent data sets, and draws two regression lines having different slopes:

[image: wrong linear regression]

What I actually want is something like this:

[image: correct linear regression]

where the two lines are parallel, as my linear model suggests.

I've tried specifying the formula explicitly in `geom_smooth()`:

```
tb %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, colour=z, z=z)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(
    method="lm",
    formula = y ~ x + z
  )
```

but I obtain the warning:

> Warning message:
> Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
> object 'z' not found

and no regression lines are drawn.

Comment: This doesn't seem like something you can do with `geom_smooth`. You'd be better off fitting the lines outside of ggplot and drawing them yourself with something like `geom_abline`. Or you could write your own custom geom but that's a bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a far cry from simplicity and elegance one would expect from a mature statistical software, but it works:

```
lm1 = lm(y ~ x + z, data=tb)
tbPred = predict(lm1, newdata=tibble(x=x, z=F), se.fit=T)
tbLine = tibble(x=x, y=tbPred$fit, z=F)
tbBand = tibble(
  x=c(x, rev(x)),
  y=c(tbPred$fit - 1.96*tbPred$se.fit, rev(tbPred$fit + 1.96*tbPred$se.fit)),
  z=F
)
tbPred = predict(lm1, newdata=tibble(x=x, z=T), se.fit=T)
tbLine = bind_rows(tbLine, tibble(x=x, y=tbPred$fit, z=T))
tbBand = bind_rows(tbBand, tibble(
  x=c(x, rev(x)),
  y=c(tbPred$fit - 1.96*tbPred$se.fit, rev(tbPred$fit + 1.96*tbPred$se.fit)),
  z=T
))
tb %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, colour=z, fill=z)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data=tbLine, size=1.25) +
  geom_polygon(data=tbBand, colour=NA, alpha=.333)
```

and it produces:

[image: correct linear regression plot]

Comment: I wonder if something similar could be done using a glmmTMB model? I have been trying to do this and while it worked well for a glm model it didn't quite work for the glmmTMB